# Fix textarea to the bottom of the page (with keyboard) on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, phonegap-build

I try to make chat using phonegap mobile application (based on html/css/js).
The problem is that `TextArea` for text input works correctly only on old Android like 4.4 (it's strange but it is)). On other devices:

1. `TextArea` is hidden when mobile keyboard is opened (Android 5<).
2. iOS 9<: `TextArea` fixes on the top, but with some weird gap between keyboard and `TextArea`.[Chat screen on iPad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVrhH.jpg)

Layout of chat window is following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat">    
  <div class="chat__text-input">
    <div class="chat__btn chat__btn--add-photo"></div>
    <div class="chat__textarea">
      <textarea id="messageText" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="chat__btn chat__btn--send"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.chat {
    background-color: #ffe5d8;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
}
.chat__text-input {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 49;
    background-color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 2.95%;
}
```

In theory, it is enough for `TextArea` fixed bottom positioning. But it doesn't work. So, I tried to write a JS snippet to put `TextArea` block to the right place independently from bottom position.

**JS**

```
addEventListenerBySel('#messageText', 'focus', function () {
    var screenH = window.innerHeight,
        topPos = screenH - 85; //85px - height of the textarea block
    document.getElementsByClassName('chat__text-input')[0].setAttribute("style", "bottom: auto; top: " + topPos + "px");
});
addEventListenerBySel('#messageText', 'blur', function () {
    document.getElementsByClassName('chat__text-input')[0].setAttribute("style", "");
});

function addEventListenerBySel(selector, event, fn) {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        list[i].addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    }
}
```

But it also doesn't work. I tested the output of three functions for window height. Results:

iPad without keyboard:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight 480
window.innerHeight 480
window.outerHeight 0
```

iPad with keyboard:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight 480
window.innerHeight 211
window.outerHeight 0
```

Android without keyboard:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight 592
window.innerHeight 592
window.outerHeight 592
```

Android with keyboard:

```
document.documentElement.clientHeight 592
window.innerHeight 592
window.outerHeight 592
```

So you can see that on iOS devices is possible (somehow) to differ when keyboard is opened or not. On Android devices it is not possible.

So how to fix block with input in the bottom of the page on Android? Is it possible at all? Are there some crossplatform solutions is they are at all?

Expected result (simulated in desktop Chrome):

[Without keyboard](http://prntscr.com/fbkupg)

[Keyboard is opened](http://prntscr.com/fblf40)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe make the page scroll down to the input box by using it's id

```
myTextArea = document.getElementById("messageText");
window.location.hash = "#"+myTextArea.id;
```

Obviously do that only when it's an Android device when you get focus.